# Funding emulator wallets with custom currencies

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, simulator

How exactly can I fund the emulator wallets with custom currencies?
Please show an emulator example doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
import Data.Default (def)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Ledger.Ada as Ada
import qualified Ledger.Value as Value
import Wallet.Emulator.Wallet (Wallet(..))
import Plutus.Trace.Emulator (EmulatorTrace, EmulatorConfig(..), runEmulatorTraceIO', 
                              activateContractWallet)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let dist = Map.fromList [ (Wallet 1, Ada.lovelaceValueOf 100_000_000
                                    <> Value.singleton "ffff" "mytoken" 10)
                          , (Wallet 2, Ada.lovelaceValueOf 25_000_000)
                          ]
      emCfg = EmulatorConfig (Left dist) def def
  runEmulatorTraceIO' def emCfg myTrace
```

In summary, `Wallet 1` starts of with 100 ADA, and 10 tokens with currency symbol `ffff` and token name `mytoken`. `Wallet 2` simply starts with 25 ADA.

The [Auction](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/master/plutus-use-cases/src/Plutus/Contracts/Auction.hs) use-case example demonstrates that.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't find as such in the example you pointed to.

Comment: Is there a way to show the final fine-grained distribution of `Value` amongst all the wallets (i.e., all the various currencies)?

Comment: If you mean the distribution of `Value` for all the wallets at the end of emulation, then the answer is that you don't need to do anything more than the example above. The function `runEmulatorTraceIO` prints the distribution for all wallets in the terminal at the end of emulation.

Answer (score 0):

12/2022, plutus-apps v1.0.0 update on the accepted answer.

`Wallet 1` is not working anymore. You can use `knownWallet 1`.

Or you can `import Plutus.Contract.Test (w1, w2)` and then use `w1` , `w2` as your simulated wallets.

Also `EmulatorConfig` has [2 components](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-contract/html/Plutus-Trace-Emulator.html#t:EmulatorConfig), not 3. So it is:

`emCfg = EmulatorConfig (Left dist) def`

BTW I get [error when setting initial state](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/9652/custom-currency-error-cannot-build-the-initial-state-tag-tocardanopolicyid) with custom currencies.

Answer (score 0):

the easier way I found:

```
dist = Map.fromList [ (wallet 1, Ada.lovelaceValueOf 1_000_000_000 ) -- treasury
                        , (wallet 2, Ada.lovelaceValueOf 1_000_000_000  
                            <> Value.singleton yacadaNFTSymbol  (U.giveReferralNFTName )  15) -- referral
```

in : https://github.com/cmorgado/yacada_learning